# Validators not catching errors

Tags: python, validation, flask-wtforms

My validators don't seem to be catching errors. I can put in a name in the State field that is 20 characters or not enter anything and the applicable WTForm validator misses it and send it to the ORM. I want it to catch validation errors before sending to the database where it throws NOT NULL errors etc. I need to force the user to correct bad inputs before sending them to the database. What am I doing wrong?

forms.py:

```
class ShelterForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Name', 
        [validators.InputRequired(), 
        validators.Length(
            max=50, 
            message="Limit 50 characters, please try again.")])
    address = StringField('Address', 
        [validators.InputRequired(), 
        validators.Length(
            max=30, 
            message="Limit 30 characters, please try again.")])
    city = StringField('City', 
        [validators.InputRequired(), 
        validators.Length(
            max=20, 
            message="Limit 20 characters, please try again.")])
    state = StringField('State', 
        [validators.InputRequired(), 
        validators.Length(
            max=13, 
            message="Limit 13 characters, please try again.")])
    zipCode = IntegerField('zipCode', 
        [validators.InputRequired(), 
        validators.Length(
            max=10, 
            message="xxxxx or xxxxx-xxxx")])
    website = StringField('Website', 
        [validators.InputRequired()])
    maximum_capacity = IntegerField('maximum_capacity', 
        [validators.InputRequired()])
```

views.py

```
from PuppyShelter import app
from PuppyShelter import models
from PuppyShelter import forms
from flask import render_template, url_for, request, redirect, flash, jsonify

@app.route('/shelters/shelternew', methods = ['GET','POST'])
    def shelterNew():
        form = forms.ShelterForm()
        if request.method == "POST":
            new_shelter = {
                'name': form.name.data,
                'address': form.address.data,
                'city': form.city.data,
                'state': form.state.data,
                'zipCode': form.zipCode.data,
                'website': form.website.data,
                'maximum_capacity': form.maximum_capacity.data}
            models.createShelter(new_shelter)
            flash('A new shelter has been opened!')
            return redirect(url_for('shelters'))
        else:
            return render_template('shelterNew.html', form = form)
```

shelterNew.py

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.css') }}"
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <legend>New Shelter</legend>
        <form method ='POST' actions='/shelterNew' enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
            <label for="shelter-name">Name</label>
            {{ form.name(class="form-control", placeholder="Name") }}
            {% if form.name.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                    {% for error in form.name.errors %}
                    {{ error }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
            <label for="shelter-address">Address</label>
            {{ form.address(class="form-control", placeholder="Address") }}
            {% if form.address.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                    {% for error in form.address.errors %}
                    {{ error }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
            <label for="shelter-city">City</label>
            {{ form.city(class="form-control", placeholder="City") }}
            {% if form.city.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                    {% for error in form.city.errors %}
                    {{ error }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
            <label for="shelter-state">State</label>
            {{ form.state(class="form-control", placeholder="State") }}
            {% if form.state.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                    {% for error in form.state.errors %}
                    {{ error }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
            <label for="shelter-zipCode"></label>
            {{ form.zipCode(class="form-control", placeholder="Zip") }}
            {% if form.zipCode.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                    {% for error in form.zipCode.errors %}
                    {{ error }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <label for="shelter-website">Website</label>
            {{ form.website(class="form-control", placeholder="enter url here") }}
            {% if form.website.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                    {% for error in form.website.errors %}
                    {{ error }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
            <label for="shelter-maximum_capacity">Maximum Capacity</label>
            {{ form.maximum_capacity(class="form-control", placeholder="Maximum Capacity") }}
            {% if form.maximum_capacity.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                    {% for error in form.maximum_capacity.errors %}
                    {{ error }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        </br>
        <div>
        <input class="btn btn-success" type='submit' value='Create'>
        <input class="btn btn-warning" type='reset' value='Reset'>
        </div></br>
        </form>
        </br></br>
        <a href='{{url_for('shelters')}}'class="btn btn-success btn-lg active" role="button"> Shelters.</a>
        <a href='{{url_for('puppies')}}'class="btn btn-success btn-lg active" role="button"> Puppies.</a>
        <a href='{{url_for('owners')}}'class="btn btn-success btn-lg active" role="button"> Owners.</a>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution. I forgot to add `and form.validate()` to my `if request.method == "POST":`
So the error was in the view.py. Here is the working code:

```
def shelterNew():
    form = forms.ShelterForm(request.form)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        new_shelter = {
            'name': form.name.data,
            'address': form.address.data,
            'city': form.city.data,
            'state': form.state.data,
            'zipCode': form.zipCode.data,
            'website': form.website.data,
            'maximum_capacity': form.maximum_capacity.data}
        models.createShelter(new_shelter)
        flash('A new shelter has been opened!')
        return redirect(url_for('shelters'))
    else:
        return render_template('shelterNew.html', form = form)
```